# How to get Facebook share count of specific url using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, sdk, share

Hi I've looked all over the internet for days to find the answer to this question.

I'd like to know how to get the share count of a specific url using javascript and then sending the value server side using ajax.

I'd really appreciate it if you could help me out :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use their graph functional: http://graph.facebook.com/

You will have to load the page like this: http://graph.facebook.com/http://graph.facebook.com/
And the results would be returned back via json. But be carefull with long urls, they are not always returned correctly.

Hope it'll help!

Comment: Thanks John - How would I do this in javascript and send the share value via ajax?

Comment: For example like this if you are using JQuery: `jQuery.getJSON("http://graph.facebook.com/http://graph.facebook.com/?callback=?").done( function(data) { alert(data.shares); } )`

Comment: thank you I have tried doing that but instead of using 'alert' I want to put data.shares into a variable and send it to php via ajax

Comment: But what is the question then? Don't you know how to send the values with ajax? `jQuery.ajax("example.com/example.php?shares="+data.shares)` - isn't it the case?

Comment: sorry I'm a total noob - yeah I'm trying to send the value with ajax. So would you do your top script without alert(data.shares) followed by jquery.ajax ?

Comment: Ok, I will try to provide the full code for you: `$.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/http://example.com/?callback=?', function(data) { $.ajax("http://example.com/example.php?shares="+data.shares) });` after that you will be able to access `shares` from your script example.php via `<?php echo $_GET["shares"]; ?>`. And don't forget to include JQuery.